1С 8.3 Помогите разобраться как получить значение реквизита из документа в модуле объекта для движения в регистре накопления?
Я работаю с движениями в регистре накопления "Резервирование" (Измерения: Документ, Товар; Ресурсы: Количество). Движения осуществляются по документам "ЗаказПокупателя" (Приход) и "РасходнаяНакладная" (Расход). В документе "РасходнаяНакладная" имеется реквизит "Заказы", который ссылается на документ "ЗаказПокупателя". Расход должен фиксироваться строго по выбранному в "Заказы" документу и списывать весь приход, связанный с этим документом, вне зависимости от табличной части "РасходнойНакладной". Например, если я провел документ "ЗаказПокупателя" четыре раза, но мне нужно провести расход только по второму документу, и в табличной части указано количество 10, а в приходе второго документа всего 5, должно списаться только 5, несмотря на данные табличной части "РасходнойНакладной". Я новичок в 1С и не знаю, как получить значения реквизита "Заказы" в модуле объекта "РасходнаяНакладная". Пожалуйста, напишите команду для получения этого значения, и код для расхода по документу. Проверял методы Обращение к полям: Элементы.ИмяПоля
Обращение к реквизитам Объекта = Объект.ИмяРеквизита
Или Список.ИмяРеквизита - если у вас форма списка или выбора, в 1с предприятие при проведении документа выдает ошибку "Значение Объект не обнаружен"
Вот мой код на данный момент:
Движения.Резервирование.Записывать = Истина;
Для Каждого ТекСтрокаПереченьРасходнойНакладной Из ПереченьРасходнойНакладной Цикл 
        Движение = Движения.Резервирование.Добавить();
        Движение.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Расход;
        Движение.Период = Дата;
        Движение.Документ = Документы.ЗаказПокупателя;
        Движение.Товар = ТекСтрокаПереченьРасходнойНакладной.Товар;
        Движение.Количество1 = ТекСтрокаПереченьРасходнойНакладной.Количество;
КонецЦикла;
    

